# AVAudioplayer should automatically switch to next song

Tags: objective-c, iphone, avaudioplayer

i have  created a music application in which there are 90 songs.when i click on a particular song it plays. i need that when i click on a particular song it should switch to next song automatically when the current songs completes.Please help me in solving this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [AVAudioPlayerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html) to detect when a song finishes playing ([audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVAudioPlayerDelegate/audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:)). Then start playing the next song.